# Using PHP to dynamically change an image

Tags: php, html, dynamic

I've been trying to come up with something that would change an image based on the server's time; it's for a livechat which I need the image to change depending on whether we're online or not.

Here's what i've come up with so far:

```
<?php

$h = date('G'); //set variable $h to the hour of the day
$d = date('w'); //set variable $d to the day of the week
$m = date('i'); //set variable $m to minute of the hour
//G is the date key for hours in 24 format (not 12), with no leading 0s, like 02.

if ($d >= 1 || $d <=5 && ($h == 9 || ($h == 8 && $m >= 30)))  && ($h < 17 || ($h == 17 && $m <= 30))
{
    $img = '{{media url="wysiwyg/live-chat.gif"}}';
}

else
{
    $img = '{{media url="wysiwyg/Livechat-offline.gif"}}';
}

?>
```

I'm not too sure if this is correct, can someone "approve" this?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use a "smarter" logic to it:

```
$wday = date('w');
$time = date('Hi');
if (($wday > 1) && ($wday <= 6)) { // if day is between monday to friday
    if (($time > 0830) && ($time < 1730)) { // if time is between 8.30 and 17.30
        $img = '{{media url="wysiwyg/live-chat.gif"}}';
    }
}
// if $img is not set then it means it's not between the desired time-interval, meaning you are offline.
if (!isset($img)) $img = '{{media url="wysiwyg/Livechat-offline.gif"}}';
```

So, before we were checking "from monday @ 8.30 to friday @ 17.30" meaning that if we tried it at "thursday @ 2.00am" it would show as online (since you were within the time-span).
Now we are checking the time independently of the day, after checking that we are inside the day-span.

Comment: Your method is definitely more logical, I did not realise that you could put it all in one variable if that makes sense. The image I need to change is in a static block; any idea how/where I would run this? Btw thank you for your response :)

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "static block" (googling told me it had something to do with magento?) so I don't think I can help there [I know nothing of magento] [but this should yield some results](http://go.magento.com/support/kb/category/name/working-with-static-blocks/)

Comment: Ah apologies, it is something to do with magento (and maybe other CMS's). I shall look up the rest by myself. Thank you for the reference though!

Comment: i just realised that the code you posted covers all time between the two dates and times; I need the image to change at 8:30 each day to "online" and 17:30 each day to "offline". Would I need to repeat this code for each day and change the second condition to '($dd < 11730)'?

Comment: Completly forgot about that scenario. I'll think about something and edit the code ASAP

Comment: Aha, it's fine. I've changed it to this for now:

    if (($dd > 10830 && $dd < 11730) || ($dd > 20830 && $dd < 21730) || ($dd > 30830 && $dd < 31730) || ($dd > 40830 && $dd < 41730) || ($dd > 50830 && $dd < 51730))

Comment: @AaronEDPA Edited the code above to account for that sad mistake :)

Comment: That's cleaner than the code I had produced! Many thanks MoshMage :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to check if the current time is between your opening hours.
Something like this:

```
<?php
if(strtotime("now") < strtotime('date1') && strtotime("now") > strtotime('date2')){
 // do your thing
}
else{
 // do something else
}
?>
```